# Find first instance of open in email history

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains the email history for all of my company's email marketing campaigns. The table has a record of each email that was sent to each user in our system. I'm trying to write a MySQL statement that will start at the first instance of when someone was sent an email from the company (using one of the fields in the table (timestamp) as a min), find the first instance where they opened an email, and count the number of emails that they received until their first open. Any thoughts on how to structure that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM emails
WHERE recipient = 123
  AND email_id > (SELECT MIN(email_id) FROM emails WHERE recipient = 123 AND email_status = 'opened')
```